# Should I always use size_t when indexing arrays?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, virtual-memory, size-t

Do I need to use `size_t` always when indexing an array even if the array is not big enough to exceed the size of an int?

It's not a question about when I should use `size_t`. I just want to know if, for example, a program having 2GB of available memory (all of these fields can be indexed by an int32) but with this memory being (virtual memory) assigned to the "fields" 14GB - 16GB of the computer's RAM.

Would it always fail when indexing the memory if I used an `int32` instead of a `size_t` (or an `unsigned long int`) in this case?

Maybe the question is more about virtual memory than about pointers.

Comment: Indexing an array doesn't have to do with host machine's RAM. The reason why `size_t` is encouraged is because it makes your program portable.

Comment: Typically a program should not need to care how much memory is installed in the machine it is running on. But if the program logic dictates that there will be a lower limit on the number of elements then you could use a smaller index type.

Comment: `size_t` is guaranteed to be able to index every byte of anything you throw at it. Handy sometimes.

Comment: You can use any integral type that is large enough to hold indices of your array. `char` is OK for small arrays. It has nothing to do with the amount of total amount of addressable memory, or virtual memory, or whatever. `size_t` is able to hold any index of any array so it's useful if you don't know the size upfront.

Comment: @user4581301: The C standard does not offer such a guarantee.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: it does. Specifically, it can hold the size of the largest possible array, since an array is a type of object. Therfore, if you can index it, the size (in bytes) fits in an size_t. And since array elements are at least one byte, so can every index. The confusion might be because size_t is not guaranteed  to hold the sum of size of multiple objects.

Comment: @MSalters: It does not. The C standard specifies (C 2018 7.19 2) that `size_t` is the unsigned integer type of the result of the `sizeof` operator. But that just tells us about the type, not about the value. The standard does not guarantee that sizes will not overflow the type, any more than it guarantees that arithmetic operations will not overflow the various `int` types.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`size_t` is an unsigned integer that is capable of holding the size of the largest object you can allocate. It is useful for indexing because this means it can index into the largest array you can allocate.

This does not mean it is required or even necessarily recommended for indexing. You can use any integer type that is large enough to index the array. `int_fast32_t` might be faster, `uint_least16_t` might be smaller in a structure, and so on. Know your data, and you can make a good choice.

One consideration you should make is that on some platforms, using a signed index might require an extra sign extension instruction. As an example, here is x86-64:

```
// ; zero-extending idx (in edx) is "free" by simply using rdx.
// movzx eax, BYTE PTR [rcx+rdx]
// ret
char get_index(char *ptr, unsigned idx)
{
   return ptr[idx];
}

// ; sign extending idx from 32 bits to 64 bits with movsx here.
// movsx rdx, edx     
// movzx eax, BYTE PTR [rcx+rdx]
// ret
char get_index(char *ptr, int idx)
{
   return ptr[idx];
}
```

Virtual memory is outside the scope of C or C++. From their point of view, you simply index into memory and it's up to your platform to make it work. In practice your app only uses virtual addresses; your CPU/OS is translating the virtual address to a physical address behind the scenes. It is not something you need to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to use `size_t` always when indexing an array even if the array is not big enough to exceed the size of an `int`?

No because the index is not the address or even a byte offset.  It's a value used to compute an offset from a pointer.  As long as the integral type is large enough to represent the largest index, then you can access any element in the array.

That said, there are some details of how different types are treated in the context of an array index.  This question is tagged with both C and C++, and while there's a lot of similarity, there are some extra gyrations that can come into play with C++.  But let's start with the common parts.

To simplify this explanation, let's assume you have a machine with a 4GB address space and 16-bit `int`s.

```
int a[8000];
```

Obviously, this declares an array of 8000 `int`s, indexed from 0 through 7999.  The compiler treats the `8000` literal as an `int`, so there are no real surprises.

But had the literal been `0x8000`, it'd get more complicated.  Since a 16-bit `int` cannot represent 32768 (the decimal equivalent of 0x8000), it has to choose a different type, like a `long`.  But, believe it or not, if the literal was expressed in hexadecimal, it'll choose an `unsigned int` instead.  (The rules for literals are not quite the same as the rules for integral promotions.)  It won't actually matter here, since the net effect is the same.

Notice that if we used 0x8000, we'd have created an array that can be completely *indexed* using a 16-bit `int`, but we'd have to use a different type to represent its *size*.

Indexing in C is quirky, and C++ inherits this quirkyness.  The languages don't care whether you swap the index and the name of the array.

```
a[3] = 42;
printf("%d\n", 3[a]);  // legal, and prints "42"!
```

You can even index from a pointer into the array and use negative subscripts (as long as the reference is still inside the same array or one element past its end).

```
a[3] = 42;
int *p = a + 6;
printf("%d\n", p[-3]);  // also legal, and prints "42"!

// off-topic
printf("%d\n", -3[p]);  // legal, but does *not* print "42"!
```

That tells us indexes can be signed integral types, but `size_t` is always an unsigned integral type.

All of the above also applies to C++, but C++ has some additional wrinkles if you think about the standard library container types like `std::vector` and `std::array`.

The standard containers define their own size types, like `std::vector::size_type`.  These are almost always the same underlying type as `std::size_t`.

The standard containers are just classes defined in the library, so the quirky swap-pointer-and-index syntax doesn't work with them.

```
std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
std::cout << 3[v] << '\n';  // std container types cannot emulate this
                            // kind of array indexing
```

So what type must the index be?  Well, we know it's legal to write this:

```
std::cout << v[3] << '\n';
```

And we know that a literal `3` is treated as an `int`, which is signed and likely has a smaller range than `std::size_t`--er, `std::vector<int>::size_type`.  Hopefully, that makes it clear that you don't need to use the size type for the index as long as whatever type you're using can represent the desired index.

Indexing with the standard container types is implemented by overloading `operator[]` on the container's size type.  So, `3` may be an `int`, but, in order to match the definition of the overload, it will first be converted to `std::vector<int>::size_type`.

In other words, with the C++ standard container types, you are effectively always using `size_t` for the indexes, regardless of what type you actually use.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid program failures the programmer should always use an index type that is at least as large as the type returned by the `size()` method. This ensures that the index never overflows any possible size of the array. The implementation of an array is usually making sure that its runtime size never overflows the type returned by the `size()` method. This means the index type should be:

- `size_t` in case of `char[N]`, `uint8_t[N]`, `int[N]`, etc
- `size_t` in case of `std::vector` and `std::list`
- `int` in case of `QList` and `QVector`
- an arbitrary precision integer (aint) in case of bitarrays (if the bitarray's `size()` method returns an aint)
- aint in case of arrays compressed in memory (if the array's `size()` method returns an aint)
- aint in case of arrays spanning multiple machines (if the array's `size()` method returns an aint)
- Other languages than C++:

  - `int` in case of `java.util.Collection` and its subclasses

In summary: A safe index type is the type returned by the `size()` method.

Note: If the `size()` method returns the unsigned `size_t`, then the signed `int` and `ssize_t` aren't safe index types. In case of gcc and clang, the compiler flags `-Wsign-compare` (enabled by `-Wall`) and `-Wconversion` can be used to prevent most of these cases.